# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error when running Spring Boot application jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I have created a jar file of a SpringBoot application using gradle.However when I try to run the jar file I am getting the following error:
[image: screenshot of error message]

Here is a SS of the entire project structure along with the build.gradle file content

[image: Screenshot 2]

Cant seem to figure out the problem. Getting this error whenever I run the jar file. I created the jar file using "gradle build" command

Comment: I used the full package name :
"com.example.websocketdemo.WebsocketDemoApplication"
But it is still showing same error

Comment: Try to run `java -jar <path_to_this_jar_including_the_file_name>.jar` from the command line to see if it works. If it works, please share a screenshot of your IDEA's run configuration (IDE main menu `Run | Edit Configurations`).

Answer (score 0):

you should use full package name com.example.mywebsocketdemo. in build.gradle

Comment: I used the full package name : "com.example.websocketdemo.WebsocketDemoApplication" But it is still showing same error